# Isn't that C's assembly the same concept as C#'s IL or Java's bytecode

Tags: java, c#, c, assembly

We know that high level programminhg language like C# or Java use virtual machine and the source codes are compiled into Intermediate Language(C#'s IL or Java's bytecode), so that those program can write once, run anywhere.

But isn't that low level programming language C has the same concept "assembly" which the souce codes are compiled to. So C can also write once, run anywhere, so what are the things that high level programminhg language bring?

Comment: "*But isn't that low level programming language C has the same concept "assembly"*" - your assumption is wrong.

Comment: Generally, C programs are compiled directly into machine language. There is no intermediate language. I know some older compilers used to convert C code to ASM code then run that through an assembler, but the end result was ML.

Comment: C is (formally) a high level language. And the assembly concept in C is *machine code*. It is not processor neutral, assembly for ARM chips is quite different from x86_64.

Comment: *run anywhere* - as long as everywhere you want to run it has compatible CPUs, and the same OS.  e.g. that's why distributing compiled binaries is common for x86 Windows, but less common for other more portable OSes.

Comment: The closest things C has to "run anywhere" is *source code* -- you can compile for somewhere to run it there, and you can repeat that for each anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Platforms like dot net and Java, specify the exact semantics of each possible instruction. The runtime may then translate a sequence of instructions, to a sequence of assembly with exactly the same semantics.

C is a very different beast. The exact semantics of your C program depend on the C headers, which were provided by your OS vendor. And the rules for how each instruction maps to CPU instructions and registers, also influenced by the OS vendor.

And then there's the wiggle room of undefined behaviour. Parts of the C language definition where the semantics of an instruction are deliberately left up to the compiler to define (or not).

While some compilers will use an intermediate form when translating from source code to machine code. Some target specific decisions may have already been made while parsing system headers. Or by the rules for how argument passing and return values map to registers or the stack.

Of course you could define a fake target OS / CPU, partially compile your program to it, then build a runtime that can map those semantics to your actual OS / CPU. This is exactly the approach used by Chrome's experimental [portable native client](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client). But that discards some of the strengths of C.

Comment: 1.  The C headers dictate the semantics of the standard library functions.  The actual semantics of the compiled program are dictated by the C compiler and the processor instruction set it supports.  A compiler that adheres to the C standard should produce a program that has C standard semantics, regardless of the processor and instruction set.

Comment: 2.  Any C program worth its salt will avoid UB altogether.

Comment: Note that the C headers could define macros instead of functions. And types in the language standard are expected to be mapped to structures or integer types, again based on the OS. Then there's stuff like 'stdcall' changing semantics around call instructions.

Comment: 3.  Platforms like .NET and JAVA specify the exact semantics of each *byte code instruction.*  Execution must still pass through another stage (the JIT) that maps the byte code instructions to platform-specific machine instructions.

Comment: Sure, avoid all UB, if you can. Proving that a program has no UB, with all possible inputs,  is non-trivial.

Comment: You don't have to prove that a program has no UB; you simply avoid those techniques that cause UB in the first place.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Re “Any C program worth its salt will avoid UB altogether”: Nonsense. The only programs that can be written in strictly conforming C are limited to simple text processing and abstract mathematics. Every other program uses behavior not fully defined by the C standard, much of it undefined behavior as given by the standard. Any use of GUI services contains undefined behavior. Using network services contains undefined behavior. Calls to Unix services use undefined behavior. Commercial programs widely use compiler extensions that are undefined behavior.

Comment: @RobertHarvey clang sanitisers (and valgrind I guess) can be used to demonstrate that your program doesn't hit undefined behaviour, for the inputs you test at least. That's not a proof that your program can't hit undefined behaviour for malicious inputs, or with a different compiler. "just avoid those techniques" is easier said than done.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The assembly language emitted by a C compiler is specific to a given machine architecture and a given operating system.

Change either of those things and your assembly language cannot be used.